# Read Several Files in R - TAB Delimited Files

Tags: r, csv, readr

I would like to modify the piece of code bellow, which read several .csv (comma separated values) files, in order to inform it that the files are tab delimited, i.e., .tsv files.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

For individual files, I did (using the readr package):

```
data_1  <- readr::read_delim("dataset_1.csv", "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Any help? Thanks,

Ricardo.

Comment: Haven't tested it but something like the following should work because lapply permits additional parameters after FUN.
`myfiles = lapply(temp, read_delim, delim="\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the following:

Version 1: User defined function

```
my_read_delim <- function(path){
  readr::read_delim(path, "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
}
lapply(temp, my_read_delim)
```

Version 2: Using the `...` argument of `lapply`
`lapply` has as third argument `...` which means arguments after the second are passed to the function specified as second argument:

```
lapply(temp, readr::read_delim, delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Version two is essentially the same as version one but more compact

---

Assuming all files do have the same columns:

In most applications after reading the data in via `read_delim` you want to `rbind` them. You can use `map_df` from the `purrr`-package to streamline this as follows:

```
require(purrr)
require(readr)
# or require(tidyverse)

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
map_df(temp, read_delim, delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works perfectly. Thanks!